# Jenkins @script directory

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

I started using scripted pipelines and it's weird but jenkins checks out everything to @script directory but WORKSPACE=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Templates/Ubuntu

So I'm getting this error: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Templates/Ubuntu@tmp/durable-5b69c1ad/script.sh: line 2: templates/scripts/02_upload_iso.sh: No such file or directory

Is this expected behavior and I should change my scripts to automatically switch to @script?

Comment: Hi, where do you see ‘@script’ directory in the above error ? The ‘@tmp’ directory is created in project workspace directory for importing shared libraries, temp processing etc. Can you post your pipeline script !